# Getting data out of a private group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

At our gym, we have a private Facebook group in which announcements are posted, photos and videos of our workouts etc. 
I do not have a FB account anymore but I was wondering if I can get the data out of the group and digest it somewhere outside of Facebook.

Maybe by using the API and forwarding the posts in the group to Telegram or mail. It could be that I am overreacting because I do not like the FB business model and do not want to participate in it. But as my gym only posts in the closed FB group, I am looking for alternatives.

Or should I just create a FB account with nothing on it and only use Tor? :)

Looking forward to your suggestions.
Regards

Comment: You can’t use the API without having an account to begin with, that would be the very basis of creating an app in the first place. And even if you used some 3rd party app provider, they would still need to be provided access to the group in the first place.

Comment: @misorude access is no problem, I was a member in the past when I had an account so I can join again anytime. I am also aware that I will have to create an account to be able to use the API.

Comment: A group admin would still need to “install” your app in the group, and you would need to get your access to the Groups API reviewed by Facebook … probably a bit much hassle for something that’s only going to be used by one person? Anyway, if you want to proceed in that direction, then you should start by getting yourself familiarized with how to use Facebook’s Graph API in general, and check out the documentation regarding the specifics of accessing group content. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/group/feed, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/